# Dynamic templateUrl based on attribute value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have this data that represents a page made up of different panels...

```
{
  "panels": [
    {
      "id": "panel1",
      "type: "carousel",
      // more panel data
    },
    { 
      "id": "panel2",
      "type": "quote",
      // data
    }]}
```

...and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
// template
<section ng-repeat="panel in panels">
  <my-panel panel-data="{{ panel }}"></div>
</section>

// directive
app.directive('myPanel', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      panel: '=panelData'
    },
    templateUrl: function() {
       // panel.type ('carousel' or 'quote') determines which template to load
    }
  });
```

What should my templateUrl function be?

Comment: Do you see to $scope object? $scope.panel ?

Comment: I can't seem to access it inside `templateUrl`. `scope` inside `link(scope, element, attrs)` has it, but it's no good to me there

Answer (score 0):

Move the logic inside the `template`:

```
// directive
app.directive('myPanel', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      panel: '=panelData'
    },
    template: '<div ng-switch="panel.type">' +
                  '<div ng-switch-when="carousel" ng-include="carousel.html"></div>' +
                  '<div ng-switch-when="quote"    ng-include="quote.html"></div>' +
              '</div>'
  });
```

Comment: is there an advantage to using a directive here, seems like I could just put your ng-switch code inside my parent template?

Comment: Any problem in computer science can be solved using [another layer of abstraction](http://www.dmst.aueb.gr/dds/pubs/inbook/beautiful_code/html/Spi07g.html). You can do more things in the `link` (and `controller`) function here, like adding more classes or computing values which the templates need (e.g. number of words in the quote, or number of medium sized images in the carousel). However, following the [YAGNI principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it), you should avoid it unless you really need it.

Comment: This seems like a very elegant solution (and doesn't need another function to determine which template to use), but it's not working for me. I get an error: "Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ngSwitchWhen, ngInclude] asking for transclusion" ... it seems like ng-switch-when and ng-include are incompatible on the same element. Am I missing something - is there a way to get this answer to work?

Comment: @Rebecca Well, yes, the solution is another layer of nesting. :) Instead of having `ng-switch-when` and `ng-include` on the same element, nest the `ng-include` inside the `ng-switch-when` as another div: `<div ng-switch-when="carousel"> <div ng-include="carousel.html"></div> </div>`.